# How to activate feature in all webapp only if its in deactivated state -Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to activate a feature in all web app in a farm. I need to chek a condition if the feature is deactivate dthen only it should get activated? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Y i need the condition to acitvate only deactivated feature is because am getting error like that feature is already activated. so to avoid that need to write a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a feature is activated in a site collection, you can use follwoing powershell code:

```
$IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Site $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The feature can be deployed at any scope like Farm/Web Application/Site Collection/Web.. You need to provide different parameters based on that as below:

```
function Deactivate-SPFeature
{
    param ($FeatureID, $SiteUrl, $WebApplicationUrl)
    $Feature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $IsActiveFeature
    If ($Feature -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Warning "The specified feature ($FeatureID) was not found."
        return
    }
    If ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::Farm)
    {
        $IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Farm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($IsActiveFeature -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Warning "The specified feature ($FeatureID) is not activated on the Farm."
            return;
        }
        Write-Host "Deactivating Feature $FeatureID."
        Disable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID  -confirm:$false
        Write-Host "Feature  $FeatureID deactivated sucessfully"  -foregroundcolor Green
        return;
    }
    ElseIf ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::WebApplication)
    {
        $IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -WebApplication $WebApplicationUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        If ($IsActiveFeature -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Warning "The specified feature ($FeatureID) is not activated in the Web application ($WebApplicationUrl)."
            return;
        }
        Write-Host "Deactivating Feature $FeatureID."
        Disable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Url $WebApplicationUrl -confirm:$false
        Write-Host "Feature  $FeatureID deactivated sucessfully"  -foregroundcolor Green
        return;
    }
    ElseIf ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::Site)
    {
        $IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Site $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    ElseIf ($Feature.Scope -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureScope]::Web)
    {
        $IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Web $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    If ($IsActiveFeature -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Warning "The feature $FeatureID is not activated on the site $SiteUrl"
        return;
    }

    Write-Host "Deactivating Feature $FeatureID."
    Disable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID  -Url $SiteUrl -confirm:$false
    Write-Host "Feature  $FeatureID deactivated sucessfully"  -foregroundcolor Green
}
```

Please refer my blog post for full information:

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-deployment.html

Comment: thanks for the reply.now i need to activate the feature in all webapp except for one particular webapp by hardcoding the webapp url.am using the below code:Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell $FeatureID = Get-SPFeature a44d2aa3-affc-4d58-8db4-f4a3af053188if($IsActiveFeature = Get-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Site $SiteUrl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature $FeatureID -Url $_.Url}
}
if($webApplications = Get-SPWebApplication http://cloudx-151-145:22222/)
{Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Disable-SPFeature $FeatureID -Url $_.Url}}
}

Comment: Powershell uses operators like -eq, -ne and not something like =

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to activate feature

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "feature id" -url "url"
```